# Feature selection before or after scaling and splitting

Tags: feature-selection, machine-learning-model, preprocessing, feature-scaling

Should feature scaling/standardization/normalization be done before or after feature selection, and before or after data splitting?

I am confused about the order in which the various pre-processing steps should be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some feature selection methods will depend on the scale of the data, in which case it seems best to scale beforehand.  Other methods won't depend on the scale, in which case it doesn't matter.

All preprocessing should be done *after* the test split.  There are some cases where it won't make a difference, but if you're uncertain it's safer to do everything after splitting.  The test set is supposed to act as data your model will see in production; you won't have access to that data to help define scale (or anything else), so don't use it that way while training.

Comment: But if for example I apply a log transformation then the test set won't be log transformed and would live in another space rendering very low performance.

Comment: @Caterina You apply the same transformation to the test set, but using training set statistics.  (For log-transform there is no "statistic" to be gleaned from the training data, except maybe the fact that you thought the logarithm would be beneficial.)

Comment: Gotcha, so for example min_max scaler should be applied in each iteration of the cross-validation procedure right? since the min and max won't be the same in each split

Comment: Yes; set the "min" and "max" statistic according to the training folds, then use that to transform both the training and test folds.  (This is done in sklearn by using `fit_transform` on training folds and just `transform` on testing folds, and that's handled by all of the cross-validation methods.)

Comment: I have the following pipeline `Pipeline([('minmax', MinMaxScaler()),('reg': LinearRegression())])`, would that automatically do the `fit_transform` for the training set and the `transform` for the validation set? Or would it `fit_transform` the whole thing?

Comment: It depends on what method of the pipeline you call (see last comment for how cross-validation methods like `cross_val_score` or `GridSearchCV` will call the pipelin). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68285130/10495893 for how the pipeline calls individual steps.

Comment: I will be using `GridSearchCV` with --refit enabled.

Comment: But I am still confused since there is a difference between validation and test set. With validation set I mean the left fold for measuring performance during CV. And with test set I mean never-seen before data when calling .predict(). Would GridSearchCV perform `fit_transform` on the training+validation set or only on training? From the image you showed me it is clear that it does only `fit` this for the test set, but not sure about validation set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135998/discussion-between-ben-reiniger-and-caterina).